# Switch reference exception when importing an object

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm at my wits end with this one.  I have an object that's exported (see suffix.js), then imported into a different file (User.js).  When the code runs, I receive an uncaught reference error (see console screenshot).  What kills me is that right before the switch it outputs the value for `suffix`, the same object that it raises the reference error on.

suffix.js

```
export const SUFFIX_SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS';
export const SUFFIX_REQUESTED = 'REQUESTED';
export const SUFFIX_FAILED = 'FAILED';

export default {
  SUFFIX_SUCCESS,
  SUFFIX_REQUESTED,
  SUFFIX_FAILED,
};
```

User.js

```
import suffix from '../actions/types/suffix';
import { LOGIN, LOGOUT } from '../actions/types/user';
import User from '../actions/user';
import userInitialState from '../initialStates/user';


export default (state = userInitialState, action) => {
  console.log(suffix);
  switch (action.type) {
    case User.read.type(suffix.SUFFIX_SUCCESS):
    case User.update.type(suffix.SUFFIX_SUCCESS):
      return {
        ...state,
        details: action.payload,
      };

    case User.delete.type(suffix.SUFFIX_SUCCESS):
      return userInitialState;
    case LOGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        displayLoginForm: action.isInit ?? false,
      };
    case LOGOUT:
      return {
        ...state,
        details: userInitialState.details,
        logoutReason: action.reason,
        displayLoginForm: true,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Console Output
[image: Console Message]

Comment: What is the `lodash.templateSources` reference at the top of the stack trace?  For that matter, what is `User.read`?  Note that you _should_ be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) to write your reducers, which should eliminate the error because you wouldn't be writing the `switch` statement or the action types in the first place.

Comment: @markerikson good catch.  I didn't notice that in the stack trace, after staring at it for hours you'd think I would have noticed!  The lodash template() function is used inside of a level of abstraction to generate all of our actions for the app rather than having to type out constants for every type of result (SUCCESS, FAILED, REQUESTED, ETC) every api call.  `_.template(`${resourceName}_${topic}_<%= suffix %>`)` _should have been:_
`(suffix) => _.template(`${resourceName}_${topic}_<%= suffix %>`)({ suffix })`  edit: formatting

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, if you can switch over to use Redux Toolkit, the need for those actions will go away completely by using `createSlice` and `createAsyncThunk` (or even our RTK Query data caching API)